# How can I copy the contentsof data/ to sdcard/ without using adb?

Tags: android

Hi I need to copy/move the contents of `data/tombstones` to `sdcard/tombstones`

I'm using the command below:

```
mv data/tombstones /sdcard/tombstones

"failed on 'tombstones' - Cross-device link"
```

but I'm getting above error.

Comment: You do not have access to `data/tombstones` on production devices, and so you cannot copy it. You certainly cannot move it. Also, this question does not appear to have anything to do with programming, and so it is better asked on ForceClose.com.

Comment: is there a way to move some file on device to sdcard , once im in shell using
sudo ./adb shell

Comment: No, not unless your phone is rooted or its the directory for your own application

Comment: respecting that it's not programming related, I only share this link about "cross-device link" problem as a comment: http://androidforums.com/ally-all-things-root/190076-not-sure-how-where.html#post1692592 it helped me, hopefully it will do the trick for you too.

Comment: I was able to move (and `cp`) files with Terminal IDE: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&feature=also_installed

Answer (score 37):

## You have a SANE VERSION of the mv command

paraphrasing a few bits from lbcoder from xda and darkxuser from androidforums

> "failed on 'tombstones' - Cross-device link"

It means that you can't create a hard link on one device (filesystem) that refers to a file on a different filesystem.

This is an age-old unix thing. You **can NOT move a file across a filesystem** using most implementations of mv. mv is not made to copy data from device to device, it simply changes a file's location within a partition. **Since /data and /sdcard are different partitions, it's failing.**

Consider yourself fortunate that you have a SANE VERSION of the mv command that doesn't try anyway -- some old versions will actually TRY to do this, which will result in a hard link that points to NOTHING, and the original data being INACCESSIBLE.

> The mv command does ***NOT MOVE THE DATA!!! It moves the HARDLINK TO
>   THE DATA.***

If you want to move the file to a different filesystem, you need to use the "cp" command. Copy the file to create a SECOND COPY of it on a different filesystem, and then DELETE the OLD one with the "rm" command.

A simple move command:

```
#!/bin/bash
dd if="$1" of="$2"
rm -f "$1"
```

You will note that the "cp" command returns true or false depending on the successful completion of the copy, therefore the original will only be removed IF the file copied successfully.

### OR

```
#!/bin/bash
cat data/tombstones > sdcard/tombstones
rm data/tombstones
```

These script can be copied into some place referenced by the PATH variable and set executable.

---

## Different Interface

> If you need a different interface from adb you may move files using the ***FileExplorer in DDMS View.***

***Side note:***

You can move a file into a folder when:

- You're `root`;
- It is your app directory;
- You've used `chmod` from `adb` or elsewhere to change permissions

Comment: Android doesn't have a 'cp' command, except on devices where busybox or comparable was added after the fact.

Comment: @ChrisStratton that is correct. One might in that case use dd if=source_file of=dest_file OR the alternative way listed above

Comment: guess i can't just replace cp with dd directly, as dd doesn't have a standard behavior for exit status

Comment: I somehow was able to `mv /sdcard/emacs /data`. I'm surprised that the reverse does not work.

Comment: @mcandre and it worked? the command itself might not throw an error have you checked the data?

Comment: Don't forget to use `cp -r` otherwise you will get the same cross-device link error and you will scratch your head for hours like me.

Comment: @Shayan thanks for your comment. I can finally stop scratching my head :P

Comment: Seriously though. I understand that `mv` might not work. But `cp` needing `-r`? I'd never have thought of that.

Answer (score -4):

Basically you don't have permission to access /data/tombstones in a production version . 
It seems we have to 'root' the device first.
But I failed to root my Samsung S4 which is using Android 4.3

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.